# Spaces at end of printf statements being printed late or trimmed in C with Clion

Tags: c, printf, scanf

`printf("abc   ");` on its own prints "`abc`"

```
printf("abc   ");
printf("d");
```

prints "`abc       d`"

```
printf("abc   ");
scanf(some char);
printf("d");
```

prints "`abcx   d`"

I'm using Clion to do this. Other IDEs do not have this issue with me. Other people using the same IDE have not had this issue.

Edit: using `printf("abc%s", "   ");`, as someone suggested, does not change the behaviour at all.

Comment: Did you maybe configure Clion to execute your program in such a way that it does not take input from the keyboard, but rather from a file?

Comment: You could always do this as a workaround `printf("abc%s", "   ");`, not that it solves the underlying issue...

Comment: It's very hard to understand what your actual issue is. How can you tell that the spaces are missing exactly? What do you expect in the printf/scanf/printf case?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Interesting that `printf("abc%s", "   ");` produces the same issue.  I suggest copying and pasting the code you are entering into a text file, and doing a `hexdump`, `od -x` or similar.  Spaces should be represented by `0x20`.  If they _are_ 0x20, then there is something wrong with the way the IDE (or its toolchain) is interpreting spaces.

Comment: Output is ***line-buffered***. Meaning output is buffered until a `'\n'` character is encountered (or an input function is called). If you want the spaces to print at the time of the `printf()` add `fflush (stdout);` after the `printf()`.

Comment: Where would SO be without you David.  That's probably it.  Hopefully the OP reports back that `fflush` works for him.

Comment: And there should be lots of duplicates... Being at work, I don't have the time to find them.

Answer (score 0):

You do

```
printf((Any text) \n);
scanf((scanf));
```